Concatenating foreign tables in JPA Java
I have two Entity where one entity is referencing a foreign key from the other. I want to concat the name field from one entity and the name field of the other entity into a new dummy field.
Like so
@Formula("concat(a.name, b.name)")
private string concatName
But I'm unable to reference the foreign table in the formula. How do I go on about being able to grab that value? Thanks!

I suggest a basic course/tutorial on SQL. What you ask is a simple join between two tables. Perhaps start with the Postgres Documentation.
